# How to get the value of the checkbox in a table and the id of the object in the row of the current checked checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am currently working in Asp.net MVC in Visual Studio 2017. I am new to working with Asp.net MVC and can not get the values i am needing.

I have a table of questions that are all displayed in a table on my view page. Each one of the questions have a Boolean value that shows as check boxes when they are being displayed. I am currently trying to write a script to get the checkbox value of true or false and where that checkbox is checked I am trying to get the Id of the question in the current row.

This is my view where I am displaying the questions.

```
@model IEnumerable<CapstoneApplication.Models.Question>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}



<h2>Questions: Admin View</h2>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/SaveCheckBox.js"></script>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create Question", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsPartOfGame)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category.CategoryName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QuestionDescription)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem=>item.IsPartOfGame, new {onclick = "SaveCheckBox(this)" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionDescription)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = item.Id}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = item.Id})
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This is the script I am currently using.

```
function SaveCheckBox(checkboxInput) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Index', 
    data: {idValue: checkboxInput.closest("tr").getAttribute("id"), 
    newValue: checkboxInput.checked }, 
    dataType: 'json'

     });
}
```

Finally this is the method the script calls to give the values to.

```
 public ActionResult Index(bool? newValue, int? idValue)
    {
        //save to database here
        var questions = db.Questions.Include(q => q.Category);
        return View(questions.ToList());
    }
```

The problem I am having is that newValue always returns the correct value of being either true or false but idValue is always null it never grabs the id of the question in the row of the checkbox that was checked.

Comment: Your `<tr>` elements do not have any `id` attribute there for `checkboxInput.closest("tr").getAttribute("id"),` returns `null`

Comment: And not related, but your `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` method is generating suplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html.

Comment: Your code will also throw an error because you specify that your return `json` when you actually returning html (and you never do anything with the view you return anyway so its not clear what you expect this code to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would place the id as the data attribute in your CheckboxFor

```
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(
       modelItem=>item.IsPartOfGame
     , new {onclick = "SaveCheckBox(this)", data_itemid = item.Id}
   })
```

Then I would use this for your javascript

```
function SaveCheckBox(checkboxInput) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'Index', 
    data: { 
       idValue: checkboxInput.dataset.itemid
     , newValue: checkboxInput.checked
    }, 
    dataType: 'json'
});
}
```